Kids show with martial arts elements and magic
I've been trying to find the name of a TV show that I used to watch a few years back (more than 10, I think). I can only remember that it was about some kids who trained in some martial art by a master, but they had some magic backpacks and magic gloves (or, I think, just one glove). Each of them had a particular color emanating from their gloves. The main actor had purple, I think...

Possibly the obscure Cyberkidz. From Youtube:

TV series from 1996 featuring Zorak, the thousand-year-old evil wizard; Zeist, his henchman; and Kyle, Ian, Danica and Zak (K.I.D.Z. - get it?), who use the Power of the Glove to protect Cyberland and Earth.

They have VR gloves projecting 4 different colors and are trained to fight evil by... a programmer's floating head? Why not. All 13 episodes are available on Youtube. Here are the kids:


Kinda like a Power Rangers crossed with The Karate Kid. I can just imagine the sales pitch for this show...

TBH I think the only one with actual martial arts skills is the Asian kid. (Sorry. I didn't write this thing...)
